# Celery / redis value too large for Redis backend

Tags: python, redis, rabbitmq, celery

We are using celery 5.2.3 with redis-server 6.2.6 as backend and rabbitmq 3.9.10 as broker:

```
backend="redis://redis/0"
broker="amqp://guest:guest@rabbit:5672//"
```

Redis and rabbitmq run from the standard dockers with default configuration.

When posting huge tasks (about 700 Mb in size) with celery, we get
value too large for Redis backend

As [the 512 MB String size limit has been removed in redis 5](https://github.com/redis/redis-doc/pull/1653), I used the redis-cli to increase these values:

```
config set client-query-buffer-limit 20737418240
config set proto-max-bulk-len 15368709120
```

That didn’t do the trick – I still get the error about the value being too big. There are many articles about this problem, but they were mostly written before proto-max-bulk-len was introduced in redis. Is there any up-to-date / additional information on how to lift this limit?
Is setting the limit in the CLI OK, or does it have to be done at startup?

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: I do not think the problem is in Redis configuration. Celery most likely does not accept such large taks (more likely you pass enormous objects as parameters, right?). If you do this, you are definitely doing it wrong. Instead, upload large objects to a Redis server, and pass its key as parameter to your task. The task itself will grab the object from Redis, and do some processing.

Comment: Thanks @DejanLekic for your answer. You are of course right, the celery messages are of monstrous size and it is a bad way of using celery. However, it happens in a running system (that was implemented a while ago by someone else) and it worked fine until we recently had a slightly bigger project to run. As other articles seem to indicate increasing the size is possible, I live in the hope to push it over the edge by tuning it, rather than rewriting it.